# Clothes rigging/movement issues 2.79

Tags: animation, rigging

Creating a character to do an animation but have been very unsuccessful in getting clothes to act like they are on the character. Created him in Make Human. Exported with just s shirt on so I could use that to make his robe/gown. Copied shirt and created gown. Tried many videos and even though none were that similar to mine I tried them all and it partially works when gimbal moves. Anyone else make and rig clothes in similar manner?

[image]

[image: pose]

[image: Bending]

Comment: Don't know if or how to add file for review. I did forget to mention I imported it as an .fbx file.

Comment: You can upload blend files to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com, for other kinds of files, just use google drive.

Comment: Trying another today. Exported from MH to Blender in the MH exchange format. Modified shirt to gown/robe again just no sleeves for now. It looks like now I need to assign new/proper vertex group for interactions with armature as the only parts not working are the middle parts of the robe I added/extruded.

Answer (score 1):

Look up weight painting, its much more intuitive than creating vertex groups. I would recommend DanPro's videos at Youtube. They are based on Rigify, but the weight paint section applies.

Also, there is an issue with importing, since the character's default position is lying in his back. Most 3d programs use the y axis as up/down, but Blender uses Z axis. See if your importer has a setting to make up for that.

Comment: Thank You for the info, Will definitely look up weight painting.

Answer (score 1):

Found my issues in Vertex Group Assignments. Assigning without deselecting unseen selection was causing The weirdness. Went through all groups and got them assigned properly. Working much better now.